# Pointer Events on mobile creates new pointerId on every pointerdown

Tags: javascript

To begin, I have read the [documentation that says pointerId conveys no meaning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent/pointerId)
 but to some extent it feels like it does.

When retrieving events from `pointerdown` on a desktop computer you can see that the `pointerId` property is always 1. I use this to verify if `pointerdown` event is coming from a mouse click.

However, when I open the Chrome developer tools and use the responsive mode and change it to a mobile device, let's say Pixel 2, and I click on the screen (which is simulated as a touch event) I get an incrementing `pointerId` on every click.

Now again, I understand it doesn't have a meaning but why does it stay 1 on desktop but go up infinitely on mobile?

I have inserted a simple snippet which when you run on the page it'll show 1 every click and if, you're on a desktop, click on full page and switch to responsive mode and pick a mobile device, it'll show an incrementing value.

```js
window.addEventListener('pointerdown', (event) => {
  console.log(event.pointerId);
});
```

**Update**

Thanks to the comments I realize that `pointerId` increments every time because there could be who knows how many fingers touching the screen of a mobile device so there is no way to differentiate them from others.

**Why do I need (want) to keep track of `pointerId`?**

Let's say I'm making an application that on desktop only needs the 1 mouse pointer but on mobile it requires 2 fingers to be used to interact with the application.

I need to keep track of where the left finger has been on the screen and what events it has caused and the same for the right finger. The problem comes where the incrementing `pointerId` comes in is there is no way for me to tell which finger is touching the screen.

Has anyone come across a solution for a problem like this?

Comment: with touch you can have more than one pointer on the screen at a time. Each pointer receives a new pointerId so you can track them all separately. If you're trying to check if it was a mouse event, why not use the `pointerType` property of the event?

Comment: No idea. If I have to guess, it might have something to do with mobile supporting multitouch better than desktop. Usually you only have one mouse on desktop,

Comment: @dgeare I understand it clearly now, it's not possible to know how many different pointers are touching a mobile device so it just increments indefinitely.

Comment: Matt Gaunt explains how to implement touch. Have a look it could help ->  [link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/input/touch/#touch-mouse-and-pointer-events)

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy did you find any solution or why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

It's all about multitouch. When there can be multiple pointer "down" events at a given moment, one needs distinct ids to differentiate them. Devices typically generate new pointerIds by adding one to the greatest current pointer 'down' id that hasn't been cancelled by a corresponding 'up'.

Multiple pointers is not (generally) supported on desktop browsers, so you don't get to experience the utility if you're only inspecting the ids in desktop dev-tools. There is never a pre-existing pointer with an id to increment,  so every next pointer event just gets assigned an id of either a 0 or 1 (depending on OS).

Note that "pointer" is an abstraction over mouse. It can also represent a finger-tip on a trackpad or smartphone screen, a stylus, etc. Some device/OSs acknowledge multiple pointers at one time, like most smartphone screens.

Chrome implements new pointer-id assignment differently on multi-touch devices vs chrome desktop and other OSs supporting multi-pointers. In Chrome desktop, the index is just always 1. But in Chrome/Android the index continually increments and never resets -- just keeps going up with every new pointer. With Firefox, the initial index is 0 (not 1). On FF desktop the id always 0, and on mobile the new index will be assigned as the current (previous) highest index + 1, so once all fingers are lifted up, the next downPointer will be 0 again.

Web MDN gives a good overview of functionality and how you need to store pointer events to track things properly here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events/Multi-touch_interaction